# MySQL - Use a placeholder for the value of a subquery where no rows are returned

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

This is basically the structure of my query:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo1 = (subquery here)
```

I want to detect when the subquery doesn't return any rows, and then use another value as a placeholder.

How can I do that?

Comment: try ur subquery alone and use `rowCount()` function , it returns the num of rows that has bee affected by that query. That `rowCount` in `PDO`, in mysql user mysql_num_rows

Comment: @WilliamKinaan Could you explain in further detail? I'm not very sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use left join, it will work :

```
SELECT * FROM table AS t1
left join 
table as t2 
on t1.Target = t2.Target
and t2.phase="B"
where t2.target is null OR 
OR t1.date < t2.Date
```

you can replace your conditions here by changing null ans your conditions here. 
By doing a left join you are including all rows on the left side of the join, and only matching rows from the right side of the join. Assuming a left side table t1, and right side table t2, in cases where the join condition is not met the value of any column in t2 will be be null. Since the goal in this case is to omit the where clause if our join condition is not met (targets match and the t2 phase value is 'B') we first check to see if the join condition failed, if so we return a row.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer!

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo1 = IF((subquery with count parameter as replacement), placeholder, (subquery))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try your `subquery` alone , then use this:
`mysql_num_rows` to know how many rows has been affected by your subquery, if the number is 0 then create a query with another place holder

**note**
`rowCount()` to know the number of rows using PDO

Comment: I don't think I can do that. My query's too complicated for it.

Comment: it is an easy step , just try it alone , then a simple `if` , `else`

Comment: Nope, it isn't really possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can just pass this by a condition above, like count your fetched data using using mysql_num_rwos , and assign that value to a variable and then put it in if else loop for conditions like as :

```
$a = mysql_num_rows(query);
if($a == '')
{
$a = your placeholder here;
}
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo1 ='".$a."'
```

something like that.